# Truly hands-free voice recording over bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth-audio, voice-recording

I know that there are lots of "voice recorder" apps out there.  Some of them will let you record using your bluetooth headset instead of the built-in mic.   However, all the ones I have looked at say things like "tap the button to start recording".  This defeats the purpose of what I am trying to do, which is to record thoughts I have while I am out and about walking, biking, driving, etc. when I can reach up and hit a button on my bluetooth phone, but I am not able to stop, pull my phone out of wherever I have it stashed, take off my gloves so I can touch the screen, power up the device, enter my lock code, jump to the record app if needed, and tap to start recording.  By the time I have done that I have lost my train of thought, and wasted a lot of time.

Voice activated recording is probably not going to work, because, even though my headset has some degree of wind cancellation, there is a lot of ambient noise from time to time.

I can use voice commands, which is still a bit of a pain but at least keeps me mostly hands free, that is, I can tap the button on my headset, say "activate" and my headset will connect to the phone and bring up voice commands.  However, I am not sure what I would do next.  The commands offered are things like "Go To << Shortcut >>", and "Check << Item >>" - these are the only two that seems remotely related to what I am trying to do.  I assume that maybe if I said something like "Go To Voice Recorder" it might open up the voice recorder, but I couldn't get it to work and am not sure what it expects for << Shortcut >>.  Even then, assuming that part would work, I would need to have some way of telling the app to start recording, for instance, if the shortcut was not just the app but a full-blown intent.  I am not sure how I would set that up.  There is also the question of how to stop it, but hopefully hitting the headset button again would work as that already as a similar function while on a phone call.

Am I on the right track here?  Is there some kind of app that will help me out here?  One thing I don't understand is, does the app have to explicitly support bluetooth audio for this to work?  I would think the OS (Android) would abstract away the input source, yet some apps explicitly claim Bluetooth support (even going so far as to only support it in the for-pay version) while others don't say anything about it.

Answer (score 2):

The Google Now option for Note to Self might work for you... It doesn't do a voice memo, but it will let you leave notes to yourself.

Comment: Just an update, this does work, and happily, Google actually records the audio and makes it accessible even if it fails to transcribe it.  But... the main issue seems to be my BT hardware, it takes around 13 seconds from when I tap my headset until I navigate past all the voice recognition to a state where it is actually starting to record! (compare to actual tape recorders of the past where it would start recording the instant you hit the button...)

Comment: @Michael Hi, just a quick check whether this answer actually helps the original issue, regardless of the BT response delay. If so, consider voting on the answers appropriately, thanks! :)

Comment: Also related: [Google Assistant Help - Create or edit notes on your phone](https://support.google.com/assistant/answer/9163597?sjid=8188484610604328092-AP)

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware of the [AutoVoice](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.joaomgcd.autovoice&hl=en) plug in that works with [Tasker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm&hl=en)?  Both are paid app (free version available with reduced functions and time based deadline) and offer great features; the only downside is that it involves a learning curve to effectively use them.